# What plugin is recommended for upload and download of file for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog where I would want visitors to download or play music and video files. What wordpress plugin is best recommended for such?

Answer (score 0):

As per WordPress, [CP player](https://wordpress.org/plugins/audio-and-video-player/) can be helpful Whereas here are some recommended players[audioPLayers](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/9-best-audio-player-plugins-for-wordpress/)